# how to print complement strand from input strand

Tags: text-processing, bioinformatics

I have problem to print complementary strand sequence of DNA also with reverse one
I want output like this 
**Please enter DNA sequence of template strand:
GTAAGCCGGAAGG
DNA sequence of antisense strand is CATTCGGCCTTCC
Reverse DNA sequence is GGAAGGCCGAATG**

Comment: If you're happy with one or several of the answers, upvote them.  If one is solving your issue, [accepting it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) would be the best way of saying "Thank You!"  Accepting an answer also indicates to _future_ readers that the answer actually solved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p 'Please enter DNA sequence of template strand: '

compl=$( tr 'ACGT' 'TGCA' <<<"$REPLY" )
revseq=$( rev <<<"$REPLY" )
revcompl=$( rev <<<"$compl" )

printf 'DNA sequence of antisense strand is %s\n' "$compl"
printf 'Reverse DNA sequence is %s\n' "$revseq"
printf 'Reverse-complement DNA sequence is %s\n' "$revcompl"
```

You may want to have a look at [the StackExchange Bioinformatics site](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/).

---

`read` will read input from the user (or whatever is controlling the standard input of the script).  With `-p` one may add a prompt text or question.  The response from the user is by default stored in `$REPLY`.

`tr` changes characters in a text from one set to another.  With `<<<"$REPLY"` we feed the response from the user into `tr` and `tr` changes all occurrences of `A` to `T`, `C` to `G` etc.  The result is stored in the variable `compl` (short for "complement").

`rev` is a non-standard command that reverses the text of a line.  We give the `$REPLY` string to `rev` through `<<<"$REPLY"`. `rev` is also used to compute the reverse-complement sequence by reversing `$compl`.

The three `printf` statements produces the output.

---

Example run:

```
$ bash script.sh
Please enter DNA sequence of template strand: AAACGTTTG
DNA sequence of antisense strand is TTTGCAAAC
Reverse DNA sequence is GTTTGCAAA
Reverse-complement DNA sequence is CAAACGTTT
```

---

If the DNA is stored on file with *only* DNA in it (i.e. *not* a fasta file), and assuming GNU `tac` is available (which reverses the order of lines in a file):

- The reverse sequence: `tac filename | rev`
- The complement sequence: `tr 'ACGT' 'TGCA' <filename`
- The reverse-complement sequence: `tr 'ACGT' 'TGCA' <filename | tac | rev`

Comment: -1 what kind of sicko orders nucleotides that way? (Just kidding. +1 for the prettier script. Also, I didn't know about that SE site… interesting!)

Comment: @Sparhawk :-) I will reorder them, alphabetically!

Comment: :D Haha, thank you. My OCD is happier. :p

Comment: could you answer me edited one pls

Comment: @ThanisPrucksikanont I have updated my answer, and will add explanations soon.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ echo GTAAGCCGGAAGG | tr 'ATCG' 'TAGC'
CATTCGGCCTTCC
```

See `man tr` for more details.