# converting fasta file to plain text

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, bioinformatics

how to convert fasta format with ">" to plain text file 
ex.
input :fasta file

```
>1M14
GATCGGACTAGCTAA
```

output :plain text file

```
GATCGGACGAGCTAA
```

Comment: You should consider accepting answers that have helped you.  You currently have five questions, none of which have accepted answers. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers  Not accepting answer that solves issues may decrease the willingness of others to help.

Comment: Six now. You're doing yourself no favours. Really.

Answer (score 5):

[The fasta file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTA_format) is already a plain text format.  What you want to do is convert your fasta file to a file containing only DNA sequence.

To delete all header lines from a fasta file, just delete the lines that start with `>`:

```
grep -v '^>' fastafile >newfile
```

You may want to have a look at [the StackExchange Bioinformatics site](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/).

---

The `grep -v` command removes lines that matches the given regular expression.  The regular expression `^>` matches lines that start with the character `>`.

---

See the end of [my answer to one of your previous questions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/428011/116858) for how to reverse, complement and/or reverse-complement a file containing only DNA sequence.